# Tomcat Startup exception: Failed to read schema document

Tags: tomcat7, xsd-validation

This is idp.war deployment on tomcat 7(.69)

Failed to read schema document 'class path:/schema/shibboleth-2.0-services.xsd'

in the trace it suggests some things:

1) could not find the document.

2) the document could not be read.

3) the root element of the document is not `<xsd:schema>`

I can go into the deployment: idp/WEB-INF/lib/shibboleth-common-1.2.1.jar/schema/ and see all the shibboleth-2.0- .xsd files that the Service.xml file is declaring as schemaLocations

this folder was created by tomcat deployment for tomcat so I don't know why it can't be read, I'm guessing permissions issues wouldn't apply here.

and the root element of the .xsd document is

```
<schema ... >
```

so that qualifies as

```
<xsd:schema>
```

correct or no?

Answer (score 0):

Two points:

(1) Whether a start-tag with the element-type name `schema` is effectively the same as one with the element-type name `xsd:schema` depends on the namespace bindings, which are omitted here.  (The start-tag `<xsd:schema>` cannot occur as the first tag in a namespace-well-formed XML document, so I'm assuming you're paraphrasing, not quoting.)

If the unprefixed `schema` start-tag makes "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" the default namespace, then that is not likely to be your problem.   (Hint for the next time you ask a question, though:  omitting salient information like namespace bindings makes your question less clear and less likely to get useful responses.)

(2) The error message you quote puts a blank between the strings 'class' and 'path' -- if your reference to the schema document actually does begin "class path:", then that is your problem:  Shibboleth's [documentation](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/IdPDevCustomExtension) says:

> Shibboleth defines a special URL scheme, classpath, which ensures that the schema files are resolved from the classpath.

As a matter of URI syntax, blanks are not allowed in the middle of a scheme name. You will need to start any URI you want to identify in this way with "classpath:/", not "class path:/".

Comment: I have, since posting, joined the tomcat user support emailing list and posted my issue there.  One of the tomcat folks seems to think it may have something to do with this fix: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56777

Comment: and I'm a bit confused on what you are referring to as important information.  Do you mean the ... in <schema ... > ?

Comment: Yes; when you ask people to confirm the correctness of an inference which depends on the form of the applicable namespace declarations, the namespace declarations are salient information.  There is good advice on asking effective questions in the [SO help files](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and in Eric Raymond and Rick Moen's essay [How to ask questions the smart way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Comment: Ok, thank you for the links and the advice.  I also just noticed that a space was inserted in my original post between class and path that I didn't mean to be there.  And rechecking my Service.xml file I can confirm that none of the classpath:/schema/<filename>.xsd paths have that space, but I do not have the double slash (//) that you show.  Is that the proper syntax to follow?

Comment: The generic syntax for URIs uses a double-slash there; the examples in the Shibboleth documentation don't.  I don't believe they are obligated to follow the generic syntax for URIs (however dumb it may be not to), so I've modified the strings in the answer to agree with the examples in the Shibboleth documentation.

Comment: I got a response back from the tomcat folks about this one.  Seems like the ClassPath class they use to resolve the path sent in is different between tomcat 7 and tomcat 8.  In tomcat 7 they use one named ClassPath that will return null because it cannot handle a leading slash and in tomcat 8 they use URLClassPath which can handle a leading slash.